# Do I really need to normalize my database?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I recently asked a question and users answered is that I should normalize my database but I don't think I should really do it..

The logic goes like this

Am storing scripts in the database which are executed dynamically according to the user..

So for example there's a script table

```
script_id | script_name
+----------------------+
12345       demo1
54462       demo2
90874       demo3
43058       demo4
```

And now the user table

```
allowed_script_ids
+-----------------+
21345|90874
```

So this is simple here, but what happens is if I delete say `script_id` `90874`, but it doesn't remove the record from the user table so they suggested me for normalizing the database, but what if user has access to 1000 scripts? do I need 1000 records for that? Or I should continue with the way am going? Even If I insert each record entry for each access, I need to delete those everytime I revoke the access for that user.

Comment: Yes, if the user has access to 1000 scripts, then that's 1000 entries for that user in the `allowed_scripts` table.

Comment: Keeping with the 1000 scripts idea, you'll end up hitting row size limits if you don't start normalising I reckon.

Comment: Take a look @ [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Are you able to describe those 1000 scripts with a category? That would negate needing to set up permission to each of them individually.

Comment: @halfer that's too much, each user, insert entries on access, remove entries on revoking the rights, and what if there are 100 users for this? 100x1000, doesnt make sense to me

Comment: @RandomGuy - aha, I misread the format of the `allowed_script_ids` table. I thought that was a user<->script many:many relation, which sounded fine. Yes, don't have a concatenated list - put `scripts` in its own table, and have 1000 entries as I described in a join table between `users` and `scripts`.

Comment: Can scripts be used by multiple users? The only reason you'd need a `userid/sriptid` join table is if that were the case (or if you were only going to store unique script entries).

Comment: @BradChristie yap they can be accessed by multiple users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1000 rows are not a lot (in the same light, nor is 10,000,000), normalising your database (ie. associating users to scripts) is perfect fit for this. If you're concatenating a string, unless you're using `TEXT` (which is baaaaad for this anyway!), you're probably going to hit some form of field length limit before you can add too many script IDs anyway.

So yes, I would also suggest that your normalise to this extent:

`Script`

```
script_id
name
```

`User`

```
user_id
...
```

`User_Script`

```
user_script_id
user_id
script_id
```

[image: Visualisation]

.. each relationship will then go into `User_Script`.

This is much cleaner than concatenating a string, and upon deletion, seeking/replacing from a string. It will be faster, cleaner, and help you actually see your database in a much more streamlined way.

Currently, how would you get all of the script names out of the database? With the above somewhat-normalised design, you can run this query similar to this:

```
SELECT `user`.`first_name`, `script.name` FROM `User_Script`
INNER JOIN `Script` USING (`script_id`)
INNER JOIN `User` USING (`user_id`)
```

Comment: 1000-user? so if each system has 10 to 100 users just multiply the rights like 1000x100...

Comment: @RandomGuy Correct. This is not a lot.

Comment: What if am storing all the script id's with a separator in a single field, any bad thing in this?

Comment: @RandomGuy - Don't you have almost exactly the same storage requirements for your current design?

Comment: @RandomGuy Yes, that's terrible and is exactly the problem you have at the moment.

Comment: So I need to take the permission on the user level so that the rights to be created will be pretty less

Comment: @RandomGuy - At work I use tables with 30 million or so rows without any problems. Believe me, 100,000 rows is peanuts.

Comment: @GarethL LOL let's see how I can handle this packet of peanuts

Comment: Good answer, with a diagram too. +1

Answer (score 2):

I would normalise that data, yes. A third table that links users against scripts is what you should do.

If a user has access to 1000 scripts, sure that will mean 1000 entries in this new third table, but that's fine. You'll find that the data is easier to manage, and if, like you say, a script is removed, it's trivial to also remove its entry in this 3rd table, without having to resort to awkward substring routines in a delimited field in the users table.

Don't worry about the number of rows this will produce in the new table, MySQL is perfectly capable of handling millions of rows in a table with ease, and if you create decent indexes, it will allow you to join those 3 tables extremely quickly, probably more quickly than performing substring matches as you'll have to do now.

Comment: @RandomGuy - Aren't 1,000 scripts in a single record a bigger mess?

Comment: No, it won't end up a mess, t's actually the preferred pattern for this sort of data model. For example, querying for all scripts that a user can run would look like this: SELECT * FROM scripts s LEFT JOIN allowed_scripts a ON a.scriptid = s.scriptid WHERE a.userid = 12345

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I pass the id only with the separator

Answer (score 0):

You could use a status bit to indicate access for the use. By this way you are getting the advantage of quick access with an index of unique script id , and for updation all it takes a resetting of your boolean bit

For example

```
    user access
    script_id user_id isGranted
    ----------------------------
    21345     some_user_id yes
```

And, your original idea of using a string and sift through it for possible scripts to which the user has access to might be inefficient if you have to constantly give or take access to a script based on the user's preference

consider this

```
    12|34|45|56|
```

what if you have to grant or revoke access to script 56 repetitively . . . .you cant retrieve and process strings for this repetitive action which is needless and also inefficient. In that case, setting a boolean bit helps and saves a lot of processing trouble